# How to make multiple copies of the same image, but with different filenames?

Tags: windows, jpeg

Shortly, I'll be required to rename 22,000 .jpg files from **imagereference.jpg** to **itemcode.jpg**.

The rename itself isn't a problem, the issue lies with several thousand of the images are currently referenced numerous times, meaning I'll need to create a single image for each item code, for example...Item codes 755117, 755118, 755119 & 755120 all currently use a single .jpg (image reference cly123.jpg) as their image, whereas they all now need to have a .jpg each named with their individual item code.

While it's easy enough to manually dupliate cly123.jpg four times and rename them 755117.jpg, 755118.jpg, 755119.jpg and 755120.jpg, I have over 7,000 items codes referencing 2,700 images, and in a couple of cases, over 50 item codes all currently use the same image, so I'll need to duplicate the image another 49 times before I can rename them to the new itemcode.jpg

I have a list of all the item codes, and which image they currently reference - is there an easy way to automatically duplicate the images the required amount of times each as per the list, or am I going to have to bite the bullet and do them manually?

Comment: Do the names have to coincide with the image references?

Comment: Where are the file names being referenced multiple times - in a database?

Answer (score 1):

Programming this is your best bet, taking in a list with the references -> itemcode mapping. Could be done in pretty much any language.

But since you're asking your question on SuperUser, and not on StackOverflow, I assume this is not an option. In that case, a renaming tool like [FilerFrog](http://www.filerfrog.com/) can speed things up, although that is definitely not going to cover everything.

Comment: Cheers, I'll give FilerFrog a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid duplicating the images by using [hardlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to make it appear like all the needed jpg files exist independently when it's actually just one file. You can make these in Windows 7 with the `mklink` command-line utility. On Windows XP you can use the free [junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) utility to create them. Either of these utilities could be used in a batch file to make large numbers of them programmatically.

There's a also a nice utility named the [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at) which integrates with Explorer, but that wouldn't be much help making lots of them automatically.

Comment: Thanks, sadly we do require multiple images, as they'll be getting uploaded to numerous different places/burnt to CD etc..

Comment: I don't think you understand. A hardlink is a way to give the same file many different file name without duplicating the actual contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

**Bangs head on desk**

Sorry, I've just realised, all I needed was a simple batch file to copy/rename the images based on the list I already had.

Y'know when something's so obvious, you just can't see it....yeah, that....

Thanks for the replies, much appreciated.